# Node.jsでCouchbaseの検索について

Tags: javascript, node.js

現在Node.jsでCouchbaseを利用しています。
Viewを利用して検索することはできたのですが、そこからさらに絞るためにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？たとえば作成日の範囲を指定してあげたらその範囲だけのデータだけを取り出すなどです
以下コードです。

```
var ViewQuery = couchbase.ViewQuery;
var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('couchbase://****');
var bucket = cluster.openBucket('beer-sample');
var query = ViewQuery.from('listtest', 'list_test');
bucket.query(query, function (err, res, meta) {
    console.log(res);
});
```